# AngularJS ignoring a key in an watched object or overriding the $watch listener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm deep watching a property that is bound to multiple controls:

```
$scope.$watch('config', function(){}, true);
```

the config itself contains various parameters:

- scale
- point
- aggregates
- current

I want to ignore changes to *scale* when it is changed by a specific control and a specific function.

Is there a way to ignore a specific property or override the watch is specific cases?

---

**For now this is what i'm doing:**

The dataChange now fires only on certain changes, in this case when other properties,
not zoom are changing.

In order to disable the dataChange for a specific zoom case i just assigned it to the rest of the cases.

I'm using Switch and not if/else just because it's more descriptive and easily extendable for more cases.

```
  $scope.$watch('config', function(n,o,scope){
   $scope.config = n;
    if (n != o) {
     switch(true){
      case n.zoom != o.zoom:
      break;

      default:
         $scope.dataChange($scope.dataTable);              
      };
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "specific control and a specific function"

Comment: The zoom property is modified by more than one control but in different ways so that dataChange is not always necessary. I wanted to override it somehow but now it's just out of the $watch listener for the zoom case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as far as I know, but a simple check would do the trick:

```
$scope.$watch('config', function(newValue, oldValue){
  if (newValue.scale == oldValue.scale) {
    // ignore this
    return;
  }
  // continue...
}, true);
```

Comment: guess that's i'll do as long as it's just one property. thanks.

Comment: If there is more then one property and at least two is changed, then this algorithm misses some changes since the key is "scale" is also changed.

Answer (score 7):

I don't like any of these answers. The first parameter of $watch is what to watch, which accepts the property name as a string, or a function to return the value. Simply use a function & return the value you want to watch. Here I use lodash JS library to $watch a new object that is based on the real object, but with the property stripped:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return _.omit($scope.config, 'scale');
}, function(oldVal, newVal) {
  console.log(oldVal, newVal);
});
```

Without Lodash [blacklist properties]:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  var myConfig = Angular.copy(config);
  delete myConfig.scale;
  return myConfig;
}, function(oldVal, newVal) {
  console.log(oldVal, newVal);
});
```

Without Lodash [whitelist properties]:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return {
     point: $scope.config.point,
     aggregates: $scope.config.aggregates,
     current: $scope.config.current
  };
}, function(oldVal, newVal) {
  console.log(oldVal, newVal);
});
```

In my opinion the other answers are not the "Angular way". This approach is not only more succinct than the other answers which are messy, but also avoids performing a redundant object comparison when the $watch fires. Keep in mind the other answers incur the cost of object comparison twice, once for the $watch itself in the Angular code, then you incur the cost of your "home made" object comparison in your callback function. My approach ensures the object comparison is only incurred once, in the Angular code, by stripping the unwanted property before feeding the object into the $watch for comparison.

Comment: Does this create a memory leak by constantly creating a new object with `angular.copy`?

Answer (score 0):

Better solution can be that function;

```
$scope.equalsAdvanced=function (sourceObject, targetObject, ignoredProperties)
                 {
                     // direct compare if there is no ignored properties
                     if (!ignoredProperties || (angular.isArray(ignoredProperties) && ignoredProperties.length<=0)) {
                         return angular.equals(sourceObject, targetObject);
                     }

                     // take the original ignored property list to a new variable
                     var ignoredPropertyList=ignoredProperties;

                     // make it array if it is not
                     if (!angular.isArray(ignoredPropertyList)) {
                         var list = [];
                         list.push(ignoredPropertyList);
                         ignoredPropertyList = list;
                     }

                     // compare property list
                     for (propertyName in sourceObject) {
                         if (ignoredPropertyList.indexOf(propertyName) >= 0)
                             continue;

                         var sourceValue = sourceObject[propertyName];
                         var targeValue = targetObject[propertyName];

                         if (!angular.equals(sourceValue, targeValue))
                             return false;
                     }

                     return true;
                 };
```

You can check the example code on fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tursoft/DpEwV/4/

This can be the better than previous;

CODE:

```
    // service
    myApp
        .service("utils", function()
         {
             self=this;

             // watchAdvanced =====================
               self.$watchAdvanced = function ($scope, exp, ignoredProperties, callback)
                {
                    $scope.$watch(exp, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                        if (self.equalsAdvanced(newValue, oldValue, ignoredProperties))
                            return;

                        callback(newValue, oldValue);
                    }, true);
                }

                 // equalsAdvanced =====================
                 self.equalsAdvanced=function (sourceObject, targetObject, ignoredProperties)
                 {
                     // direct compare if there is no ignored properties
                     if (!ignoredProperties || (angular.isArray(ignoredProperties) && ignoredProperties.length<=0)) {
                         return angular.equals(sourceObject, targetObject);
                     }

                     // take the original ignored property list to a new variable
                     var ignoredPropertyList=ignoredProperties;

                     // make it array if it is not
                     if (!angular.isArray(ignoredPropertyList)) {
                         var list = [];
                         list.push(ignoredPropertyList);
                         ignoredPropertyList = list;
                     }

                     // compare property list
                     for (propertyName in sourceObject) {
                         if (ignoredPropertyList.indexOf(propertyName) >= 0)
                             continue;

                         var sourceValue = sourceObject[propertyName];
                         var targeValue = targetObject[propertyName];

                         if (!angular.equals(sourceValue, targeValue))
                             return false;
                     }

                     return true;
                 };
         });
```

USAGE:

```
utils.$watchAdvanced($scope, "user", ["_State", "ID"], function(newValue, oldValue)
                                   {                                       
                                       $scope.changeCount+=1;
                                       $scope.logs.push($scope.changeCount + ": User object is changed!");
                                   }, true);
```

Source Code on Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/tursoft/5rLfr/2/